# how to pass value from mysql to next form in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Respected Experts!
I have one small form with few fields in which one field is not available in the form, but the value is entered in database table from backend. Now I want to passed value of this form along with (that value which generated at database table) to next form on the submission of this form. I can easily passed value which available in form by post method, But I dont knew how can I passed value of one field which generated at time of processing in mysql table. Here is my code for passing value. Please guide me how can I passed that database value to form along with other values.
**Processing code of form A**

```
<?php
    // getting all values from the HTML form
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $regdate = $_POST['regdate'];   
   
        $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
    $rel2 = $_POST['rel2'];
    $age1 = $_POST['age1'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];         
          
        $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];   
    $mble = $_POST['mble'];       
    $abc = $_POST['abc']; 
        
    }
```

**Front end of Form B where value from above  need to be passed**

```
<label>MR No:</label> <input type="text" name= "mrno"  id= "mrno" value= **need to be passed from database table**>
<label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name= "name1"  id= "name1"  value="<?php echo $name2; echo ' '; echo $rel2; ?>">
and others  in same way
```

Comment: how can i retrieve value of that record which entered at the last time ? u mean by using lastinsert id  in where clause ???

Comment: If it's an ID generated by an insert query when you process the form then yes you could use lastInsertID. But we don't know for sure because you gave hardly any details about the scenario

Comment: @ADyson ID autoincremnted ID is generated, let me try that, will show u feedback

Comment: @Adyson first i converted that mysql table into view in phpmyadmin. then by select querry i fetch data from that view by puting lastisertid in where condition, can you tell me that lastinsertid will also work with view or not ??

Comment: I don't see why not. The function returns a value. Your SELECT query doesnt really care where that value came from, I dont suppose. Did you try it?

Comment: If you need a value on the screen to be copied to some other place, use JavaScript.  See `onChange=myFunction(this, ...)`

Comment: @ADyson yes i did and its working fine untill now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX allows you to send something from the client side and immediately receive the response from the server.

For example, when the user clicks submit, you can use ajax to:

- send the form data to a PHP file...
- the PHP can use that data to look up something in the database
- then PHP can send (echo) that information (usually as a JSON string) back to the JavaScript...
- and that string is received in the AJAX `.then()` block, where you can use that data to change the page

How does the PHP file send data back to the JavaScript side? Extremely simple - use the PHP `echo` statement, e.g.:

```
$reply = 'Data to send back';
echo $reply;
```